# how to perform ocr on a selected part of the image

Tags: ocr, object-detection, python-tesseract

I'm a student working on a computer vision project for the automation of the underwriting process.
Following is an example of an old National Identity card of a Sri Lankan. I want to extract the identity card number from the image. When I perform OCR using pytesseract it could not extract the number properly. but when I prop just the number and perform OCR, it successfully identifies the number. This is not just a single use case. This should be automated, when a user enters his Identification number, my programme should be able to extract the number from the identification document and cross check it with what the user has enterd. Im stuck at the point where the extraction happens.

I got a suggestion to create and train a custom object detection model with yolo, and using that identify the part where NIC no is located, crop it and then perform OCR. I wonder whether there is a easier way of doing that other than this ? I just need to extract the  identification number from the image.

a sample image of an old NIC is provided for your reference [sample nic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZreH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

"I got a suggestion to create and train a custom object detection model with yolo"

Using Yolo for detecting where the ID number is an overkill.

Some suggestions you can try.

- Detect face using the `opencv` `face-detector`.
- Detect the thick orange line using `opencv` `threshold` function on one of the color channels.

Then crop the area above the detected face/line for the id number.